# Search for a value in a JSON field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand the "new" MYSQL JSON field.

**I have this table:**

```
id (int-11, not_null, auto_inc)
customer_id (int-11, not null)
labels (json)
```

**With this data:**

```
id: 1
customer_id: 1
labels: [{"isnew": "no", "tagname": "FOO", "category": "CAT_1", "isdeleted": "no"}, {"isnew": "yes", "tagname": "BAR", "category": "CAT_2", "isdeleted": "no"}]
```

**JSON beautify**

```
[
  {
    "tagname": "FOO",
    "category": "CAT_1",
    "isnew": "no",
    "isdeleted": "no"
  },
  {
    "tagname": "BAR",
    "category": "CAT_2",
    "isnew": "yes",
    "isdeleted": "no"
  }
]
```

And now I want to SELECT all the customers (by customer_id) in the table that have a specific **category** and a specific **tagname**

I tried this one:

```
SELECT * FROM labels_customers_json
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(labels, 'all', 'BAR') IS NOT NULL
```

But this is not what I want. This one is searching in every json attribute.
I have seen some examples of JSON_EXTRACT:

```
SELECT * FROM `e_store`.`products`
WHERE
    `category_id` = 1
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(`attributes` , '$.ports.usb') > 0
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(`attributes` , '$.ports.hdmi') > 0;

SELECT c, c->"$.id", g, n
FROM jemp
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(c, "$.id") > 1
ORDER BY c->"$.name";
```

So I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM labels_customers_json
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(labels, '$.tagname') = 'BAR'

SELECT labels, JSON_EXTRACT(labels, "$.customer_id"), customer_id
FROM labels_customers_json
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(labels, "$.customer_id") > 0
```

Comment: what version of mysql do you use?

Comment: Just installed last wamp version: mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev

Comment: Then anyone experienced on this field?

Comment: It has the correct version now, 5.7.22. My phpmyadmin was obsolete, it is 4.8.2, but still having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) to search on a specific path too. So you can use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM labels_customers_json 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(labels, 'all', 'BAR', NULL, '$[*].tagname') IS NOT NULL
```

You can also use [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) and [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) together:

```
SELECT *
FROM labels_customers_json
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(labels, '$[*].tagname'), '["BAR"]') > 0;
```

You can also use only [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) to check:

```
SELECT *
FROM labels_customers_json
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(labels, '{"tagname":"BAR"}') > 0;
```

> **demos:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rufrThAQPfXHrK9YyibFSm/2

Comment: It works, but you both answer the same. I do not know who was first to give the reptutation.

Comment: @JordiHuertas *that have a specific category and a specific tagname* - on the same object or can be different objects?

Comment: It can have different. This is a tag system to label the customers. So a tagname can have a different category in many customers. For example, it should let me find a customer that have a label "unsuscribed" from a category "email" or "postal_mail".

Comment: I was doing this saving JSON in a TEXT field, but now is so complicated to work all the JSON with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably try using `SELECT * FROM labels_customers_json WHERE JSON_SEARCH(labels, 'all', "BAR", NULL, "$[*].tagname") is not null` - although i cannot say if that is the best way to perform this query.

Comment: Like this? SELECT * FROM labels_customers_json
WHERE "TEST" IN JSON_EXTRACT (labels, "$[*].tagname"). It returns a syntax error near 'JSON_EXTRACT...

Comment: It works, but you both answer the same. I do not know who was first to give the reptutation.

Comment: according to the timestamps, mine was 4 seconds before, but sebastians is more detailed